# How to use delay in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to dalay html() output by some time. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
if (data==1) {
     $("#checked_answer"+ques_id).delay(800).html("Correct") ;

}
else {
     $("#checked_answer"+ques_id).delay(600).html("Wrong") ;
}
```

Comment: Are you specifically needing to delay by time, or only until a condition is met?

Comment: delay() only works on animations, not on other methods.

Comment: Use timeout or put code in queue in order to use delay(): `$("#checked_answer"+ques_id).clearQueue().delay(800).queue(function(){$(this).html("Correct");});`  If you are using jq 1.9 >, instead of clearQueue(), use .finish() which will cancel delay as i'm aware of

Comment: @Rogue..I want to delay specifically

Comment: I think html is not an effect. but show is, maybe that helps

Comment: @subsub show() will be put in queue only if animation is used, that's mean using `.show(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
var which = data == 1 ? 'Correct' : 'wrong',
timeVal = which == 1 ? 800 : 600;
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#checked_answer"+ques_id).html(which) ;
}, timeVal);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a timeout instead, as `delay()` is only intended for the FX queue :

```
var delay = data === 1 ? 800       : 600,
    txt   = data === 1 ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong';

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#checked_answer"+ques_id).html(txt); 
}, delay);
```

If you just have to use `delay()`, you'll have to add your `html()` stuff to the queue:

```
$('#checked_answer').delay(800).queue(function() {
    $(this).html('Correct').dequeue();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = 'correct';
var delay =800;
$setTimeout(function() {
         $('#checkedAnswer').html(val); }, delay);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do this using animation queues, then you can explicitly add the handler to change the text after the delay like this:

```
$("#checked-answer").delay(800).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).html("Correct");
    next();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gZvU7/)